# Biblatex does not reverse the first and last names of the second author

Tags: biblatex

I have the following `.bib` file:

```
@Book{sample-book,
    author="First1 Last1 and First2 Last2",
    title="A sample book",
    publisher="Public Domain Books",
}
```

Then I use `lualatex` `biber` `lualatex` `lualatex` to generate the pdf file.

However, the generated entry would look like this:

> Last1, First1 and First2 Last2, A sample book, Public Domain Books

My `biblatex` package settings:

```
\usepackage[
    bibstyle=mla,
    style=authortitle,
    %style=authortitle-tcomp,
    %firstinits=true,
    %backref=true,
    natbib=true,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be a *feature* (not a bug) of the `mla` style that you are using: the first author is written as "Last, First" and all subsequent authors are written as "First Last".

See some examples at the end of http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/01/

Answer (score 1):

You can just add

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```

after the `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Starting from version 3.3, `last-first` should be `family-given`. The older name still works, but generates a warning. Note that the `sortname` format applies only in some styles.