# biblatex: in bibliography, first author's last name comes first, other author's last names come second

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using biblatex for my references.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,maxcitenames=2,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{file}
```

In the bibliography, the last name of the first author of a book/paper is put first, while the last name of the second/third author of the book is put second (see image).

Whether I put the names in the .bib file like this

```
@book{vnm53,
    author = {{von Neumann}, John and Morgenstern, Oskar},
    title = {Theory of Games and Economic Behaviour},
    .....
}
```

or this

```
@book{brealey06,
    author = {Richard A. Brealey and Stewart C. Myers and Franklin Allen},
    title = {Corporate Finance},
    ....
}
```

is not making a difference.

[image]

How can I get it to consistently put the last name first?

Comment: What about `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}`.

Comment: I really thought there should be a duplicate for this, but all I could come up with is [Biblatex does not reverse the first and last names of the second author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106914/35864) which does not propose a solution and [biblatex - Order last-first for the names of multiple editors?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113573/35864) which might be too much.

Comment: @moewe Finding the right duplicate can be a reall pain in the *lalala* ;-)

Comment: If any of these solutions worked for you, you might wan tto indicate that by accepting (and upvoting) a answer or replying to a comment that helped. If none of the solutions were helpful, please explain why not.

Comment: Your comment helped and I couldn't find a way to upvote that: So actually replying to comments is the correct way? The link that said it was a feature, not a bug, helped me: I accepted it the way it was. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Following is possible and changes the separator between names as well, just to make it obvious what is lastname and what is firstname of whom.

[image: elenaBiblatexNameFormat]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=20]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{{{\color{red!80!black}\addsemicolon\addspace}}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{bertram,aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh I have just seen \DeclareNameAlias{author}{first-last} affects all of them

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

[Author name and first name order with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376714/author-name-and-first-name-order-with-biblatex)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).