# Changing apacite.bst

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

I am using apacite, but there are some discrepancies between the result and the style I want for journal submission. I copied the apacite.bst file and made some changes to make full names show up. But I also want to take commas and dots out, and have the second author's name in first name last name order.

> Bellows, John, & Miguel, Edward. (2009). War and local collective
>   action in sierra leone. Journal of Public Economics , 93 (11-12),
>   1144–1157

I want:

> Bellows, John & Edward Miguel (2009) War and Local Collective
>   Action in Sierra Leone. Journal of Public Economics 93 (11-12),
>   1144–1157

How should I change apacite.bst?

In the preamble I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[margin = .75in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position = top, font = large}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lscape}
```

For bibliography I have

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite-mycopy}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
```

mybibfile:

```
@article{bellows2009war,
    Author = {Bellows, John and Miguel, Edward},
    Date-Added = {2019-03-06 15:18:47 -0800},
    Date-Modified = {2019-03-06 15:19:30 -0800},
    Journal = {Journal of Public Economics},
    Number = {11-12},
    Pages = {1144--1157},
    Publisher = {Elsevier},
    Title = {War and local collective action in Sierra Leone},
    Volume = {93},
    Year = {2009}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure modifying `apacite` is the simplest way to go here, since the proper APA style it implements is quite specific and in some ways idiosyncratic. Is `biblatex` an option? If so, it would probably be a faster way to get what you want.

Comment: I found some answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376714/author-name-and-first-name-order-with-biblatex so I will close this question soon.